# Automation Tool for Electron App

Tags: desktop-application

We have a Desktop App which has been built using electron and is chrome underneath. We want an automation tool for it. Could anybody tell me what are the options to automate it?

I found [`Spectron`](http://electron.atom.io/spectron/) which is developed by Electron community only. However I am not getting anything how to start. I am not getting any good documentation or YouTube videos. Please help.

Comment: If you're on Windows you can check which accessibility technology is supported by your app. Read [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for pywinauto (GUI automation library on Python). If `Inspect.exe` can see the controls it might be useful.

Comment: @Jitendra, Checkout the link hope it will be useful [Electron With Spectron, Mocha, and Chai](https://dzone.com/articles/write-automated-tests-for-electron-with-spectron-m)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a code example on the [official Github page](https://github.com/electron/spectron)
To get started, have a look at this code snippet:

```
# Install Spectron
$ npm install --save-dev spectron
```

A simple test to verify a visible window is opened with a title

```
var Application = require('spectron').Application
var assert = require('assert')

var app = new Application({
  path: '/MyApp'
})

app.start().then(function () {
  return app.browserWindow.isVisible()
}).then(function (isVisible) {
  // Verify the window is visible
  assert.equal(isVisible, true)
}.catch(function (error) {
  console.error('Test failed', error.message)
})
```

This is an extract taken from the [official site](https://electron.atom.io/spectron/).

You want to install chai and chai-as-promised as well.

```
npm install --save-dev chai
npm install --save-dev chai-as-promised
```

Chai is a BDD / TDD assertion library for node and the second one extends it with assertions about promises.

Answer (score 1):

Along with other answers as mentioned, i will suggest Jasmine framework for spectron. I have tried mocha but faced some issues during automation.